# Is it possible to use Bootstrap’s Collapse component to hide/show elements (divs)?

Tags: forms, bootstrap-5, show-hide

I am using Bootstrap’s [Collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/collapse/) component to hide/show alternative elements based on user selection ([Form Switch](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/checks-radios/#switches)) as I would like **not to load additionnal jQuery or CSS**. I came up with this functional code but I am wondering if this is best practice since it required using *two elements (divs) with the same ID*:

```html
    <div class="form-check form-switch">
      <input
        class="form-check-input"
        type="checkbox"
        id="form-switch"
        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        data-bs-target="#collapseExample"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-controls="collapseExample"
      />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="form-switch">Switch toggle</label>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse show" id="collapseExample">Content A</div>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">Content B</div>
```